# numeric value for time series data with frequency every 2 minutes

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I have a dataset of two months in which I am getting reading every 2 minutes. statsmodel.tsa.seasonal_decompose method asks for the numeric value for frequency.  What would be the numeric value for such data and what is the proper method to calculate freq in such time series data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify frequency of the seasonality yourself.  Often this is done using knowledge of the dataset or by visually inspecting a partial autocorrelation plot, which the statsmodels library provides:
[statsmodels - partial autocorrelation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf.html)

If the data has an hourly seasonality to it, you might see a significant partial autocorrelation lag 30 (as there are 30 data points between this hour's first 2 minutes, and last hour's first 2 minutes).  I'm assuming statsmodels would expect this value; I'm assuming if you had monthly data it would expect a 12, or if you had daily data, it would expect a 7 for the weekly shape etc.

It sounds like you have multiple seasonalities to consider judging by your other post.  You might see a significant lag that corresponds to the same 2 minutes in the previous hours, previous days, and/or the previous weeks.  This approach to seasonal decomposition is considered to be naive and only addresses 1 seasonality as described in its documentation:
[Seasonal Decomposition](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html)

If you would like to continue down the seasonal decomposition path, you could try the relatively recently released double seasonal model released by facebook.  It is specifically designed to work well with daily data where it models intra-year and intra-week seasonalities.  Perhaps it can be adapted to your problem.
[fbprophet](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/)

The shortcoming with seasonal decomposition models is that it does not capture how a season might change through time.  For example, the characteristics of a week of electricity demand in the summer is much different than the winter.  This method will determine an average seasonal pattern and leave the remaining information in the residuals.  So given your characteristics vary by day of week (mentioned in your other post), this won't capture that.

If you'd like to send me your data, I'd be interested in taking a look.  Given my experience, you've jumped into the deep end of time-series forecasting that doesn't necessarily have an easy to use off-the-shelf solution.  If you do provide it, please also clarify what your objective is:

- Are you attempting to forecast ahead, and if so, how many 2 minute intervals?
- Do you require confidence intervals, monte carlo results, or neither?
- How do you measure accuracy of the model's performance?  How 'good' does it need to be?